Computing the solid angle of a arbitrary closed surface.
Wikipedia page states

An object's solid angle in steradians is equal to the area of the segment of a unit sphere, centered at the apex, that the object covers.

It also states that

The solid angle, $\Omega$ for an arbitrary oriented surface $S$ subtended at a point $P$ is equal to the solid angle of the projection of the surface $S$ to the unit sphere with center $P$, which can be calculated as the surface integral: $$ \Omega = \iint_S \frac{\mathbf {\hat r} \cdot \mathbf{\hat n}}{r^2} dS. $$ Where $ \mathbf{\hat r}= \mathbf r / r $
is the unit vector corresponding to $ \mathbf r$, the position vector of an infinitesimal area of surface $dS$ with respect to point $P$, and where $ \mathbf {\hat n} $ represents the unit normal vector to $dS$. Even if the projection on the unit sphere to the surface $S$ is not isomorphic, the multiple folds are correctly considered according to the surface orientation described by the sign of the scalar product $f $.

If I understand correctly, this formula should be valid even for closed surfaces. However, when I try to use it to compute the solid angle of a unit cube (with sides parallel to the coordinate axes) whose center is translated by an amount
$d>1/2$ from the origin, it seems to give nonsensical results. Specifically, the face closest to the origin would return a positive value (given a suitable orientation), while the face furthest from the origin would contribute a negative value to the solid angle (see the poorly drawn figure below).
Am I missing something?
What is the correct way of computing the solid angle of closed surfaces and surfaces with "folds"?
Thanks in advance.

I don't see how you get those signs. Dot product $\vec{OP}\cdot\hat n$ is negative for the nearest face, and positive for the furthest one.

The solid angle is usually defined by the surface visible from the position of the observer. That convention means all surface elements of the body where the surface normal points away from the observer are discarded and don't contribute. Ignoring this you are free to compute anything else based on your own definitions, but you need to come up with your own definitions of signs to make any sense of that. With your extended definition, back and rear surfaces that are both visible by the observer don't contribute because their contributions cancel.
